# Where did the folder option dialog go in Windows 8 preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview

Did anyone find out a way to invoke the folder options dialog in Windows 8 preview. I want to start my programs by single click and I always want to see file extensions.

**Edit:**

For hidden files and extensions this [link](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-8/) helps. But I want to get rid of the double-click too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible. Open up any explorer window then simply click `File` on the Ribbon, then click on `Change folder and search options`.

[image]

From here, you will get the normal dialog.

For single click opening choose `Single-click to open an item (point to select)` from the `Click items as follows` section on the `General` tab.

[image]

To show file extensions, choose `Hide extensions for known file types` from the big list under `Advanced settings` on the `View` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can also access it from command line / Run prompt:

```
control /name Microsoft.FolderOptions
```

Note that the menu described in the other answer to open folder options from explorer has been removed in the CP.

Answer (score 2):

New location on the ribbon: View tab > Options > Change folder and search options

[image: Screenshot of changing folder and search options]