# set same view setting to all folders in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the folder option dialog go in Windows 8 preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/345091/where-did-the-folder-option-dialog-go-in-windows-8-preview)

I want to set the same view settings(Large icons) for all the folders in windows 8.I have never tried it on older versions on windows,but now when I googled for it I only get instructions till windows 7,and the options given in these instructions are not available in windows 8.like `apply same setting to all folders`.

Please tell me how to do it in windows 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the **Change folder options** page in **Windows Help and Support**

> ### To apply a view to other folders
>
> You can customize a folder to appear the way you like it in File
> Explorer, and then apply the view to other, similar folders (folders
> that are optimized for the same kind of file).
>
> 1. Tap or click to open Computer.
> 2. Expand a location to get to a folder that isn't in a library, and open the folder.
>
> Note: Changing the view of folders that you access through libraries
> works a little differently. If you open a folder under Libraries in
> the navigation pane in File Explorer, and then change the view, that
> view is applied to all the other folders that you access through the
> library as well. You can also change the kind of file for which the
> library is optimized. Select the library in the navigation pane, tap
> or click the Library Tools tab, and pick a kind of file under Optimize
> library for.
>
> 3. If the folder isn't optimized for the right kind of file, change it. Tap or click the Home tab, tap or click Properties, tap or click
>    the Customize tab, and pick one of the choices in the Optimize this
>    folder for box.
> 4. Use the View tab on the ribbon to change the folder view—the layout (icons, list, details, and so on), sorting, grouping, the columns that
>    appear, and the other file info that appears.
> 5. Tap or click the View tab, and then tap or click Options.
> 6. In the Folder Options dialog box, tap or click the View tab, tap or click Apply to Folders, tap or click Yes, and then tap or click OK.
>
> Note: The Apply to Folders button won't be available if the folder you
> selected in step 2 is in a library.
>
> 7.
> **If you want to view all folders on your PC using the same view, repeat steps 1-5 for each of the five folder types (General items,
> Documents, Pictures, Music, and Videos).**
>
> Note: When you apply a view to folders that are optimized for a
> particular kind of file, the view will also be applied to any new
> folders of that type.